# List iteration, creation, or comprehension

Tags: python

I suspect that this can be done in a much neater way using list comprehension in python:

```
poses = []
for x,y in get_points(spline):
    pose = Pose2D()
    pose.theta = 0
    pose.x=x
    pose.y=y
    poses.append(pose)
return poses
```

Is there a way to create a nice one liner for the above? (I do not have a constructor that takes the three arguments for Pose2D)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def make_pose(pt):
    pose = Pose2D()
    pose.theta = 0
    pose.x, pose.y = pt
    return pose

poses = [make_pose(pt) for pt in get_points(spline)]
```

Alternatively, you could subclass `Pose2D` to give it an appropriate constructor.

Comment: I'm wondering why this solution isn't accepted (yet)

Answer (score 2):

for completeness sake there's also the [map builtin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) in pythong 2.x. Using @hughbothwell's example:

```
poses = map (make_pose, points)
```

which is essentially the same as

```
poses = [makePose(pt) for pt in get_points(spline)]
```

Map is handy for shortening ths common pattern, but I think Guido has officially disowned it for the future

Answer (score 1):

In case it's useful you could write a more general object maker function for classes that don't have constructors of the type you want.

```
def make_object(Class, **kwargs):
    """ Returns a new object from Class, with the attributes specified as keyword arguments """
    object = Class()
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(object, key, value)
    return object

poses = [make_object(Pose2D, x=x, y=y, theta=0) for x, y in get_points(spline)]
```